# Why are my navigational properties null when retrieved from the database in EF 4.2 POCO?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

I have a exceedingly simplistic data model (below).  I am having trouble figuring out how I am to get my navigational properties to load from the database.  I have no trouble getting them in, but the navigational property does not get set by EF it appears.  I have seen several related questions, but they are slightly different or rather involved.  I am looking for information on how navigational properties are treated by EF 4.2 (POCO).  In the reading I've done, I got the impression that I would be able to access objects with foreign keys using navigational properties.  Instead, my properties are coming back as either null or empty depending on if I instantiate my collection in the constructor.

```
public class AnimalDb : DbContext
{
    public static AnimalDb Create(string fileName)
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        return new AnimalDb(fileName);
    }

    private AnimalDb(string fileName) : base(fileName) { }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Traits = new ObservableCollection<Trait>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Trait> Traits { get; set; }
}

public class Trait
{
    public Trait()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is some (simple) code that uses it:

```
foreach (var animal in db.Animals)
{
    foreach (var trait in animal.Traits)
    {
        //animal.Traits count is 0, so this does not run.
        //However there are traits in the database, as my populate
        //function is working fine.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", animal.Name, trait.Name);
    }
}
```

----Edit Answer Summary----

Using the article and information provided in the answers below, I was able to discover I could either eagerly load using db.Animals.Include() or enable lazy loading.  There is a trick to enabling lazy loading and being able to use it though.  First to enable lazy loading I added:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Next I changed my Traits collection in the following manner:

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<Trait> Traits { get; set; }
```

Making it virtual allows the ***automatically generated proxy*** to lazily load Traits.  That's it!  IMHO I think the MSDN docs should shout this load and clear in the POCO EF 4.2 coding conventions.  Again thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't done a lot in EF 4.2, but I know in EF 4 you have to enable Lazy Loading and Proxies, otherwise you have to tell the ObjectContext to explicitly load the Nav properties, either with `ObjectContext.Load()` or `ObjectQuery.Include()`.  Is it the same with the `DbContext`?

Comment: I have attempted to gain access to ObjectContext methods such as these, but they don't seem to be available via DbContext.

Comment: When you're using `DbContext` you don't have access to all the same methods as you would with the `ObjectContext`, it's only a small subset. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696165(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use lazy loading you have to explicitly tell EF to load the relation with the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
foreach (var animal in db.Animals.Include(a => a.Traits))
{
    foreach (var trait in animal.Traits)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can read more about eager loading in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx).

Comment: This Just Works.  Still reading the article, but it appears that this will be the route I use in my particular problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few reasons that your wire-up methods may appear to have no data.  To load related data you need to :

- explicity load the data
- meet the lazy loading requirements, or
- use eager loading using `Include()`

My guess is that you turned off the virtual proxies. There is more on the requirements here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456855.aspx

Comment: I am probably most interested in the last two bullets you cite.  I see Include() is likely my best route for the short term, but may spend some time trying to understand how lazy loading is accomplished.  I have not overridden any of the POCO defaults in this simple example so I do not understand how virtual proxies could have been turned off.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Turns out the key to using lazy loading was turning it on and setting the property to virtual.  In other words, I met the lazy loading requirements.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nate Yeah, lazy loading isn't a big deal to turn on.  The change makes the T4 templates adds the word 'virtual' to all properties and proxies are turned on.  Just be aware that the proxies do add some overhead.  Also, run SQL Profiler till you get a feel for how/why the lazy loading fires off queries.